# Count number of cells in a range that match the content of a different cell

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, countif

I am trying to use `COUNTIF` in Excel to find how many items in a range match the contents of a separate cell. The idea is, the range contains everyone's answers to a given question (a one-word, non-numeric answer); the comparison column contains the correct answer. I want a count of how many people got the answer correct.

I tried: `=COUNTIF(C16:BT16,"=BU16")`

But it appears `COUNTIF` won't let me reference a cell with the criteria in it -- it requires the match criteria directly in the formula, such as `=COUNTIF(C16:BT16,"DEN")`. I can do that, of course, but I'd have to edit dozens of formulas every time I evaluate answers, and it would be much less timeconsuming if I could just enter the answers in column BU.

I also tried `COUNTIFS`; it allows multiple criteria, but also doesn't allow referencing the criteria to a different cell. Searched several different Excel websites too, any suggestions? Many thanks!

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: Excel for Mac 2011 - note that the syntax =countif(c16:bt16,bu16), as suggested below, works!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try removing the quotes and equal sign from `"=BU18"` - that will indicate that you are passing the value at that cell, which I believe is what you're looking for.

```
=COUNTIF(C16:BT16,BU18)
```

Assuming `BU18` contains `DEN`. Your first example (`"=BU18"`) is saying "count if any of these cells have a value of `"=BU18"`, which won't match anything (unless they answered some weird questions :) ).

Comment: Exactly right. Had tried it w/o the quotes, but assumed it at least wanted an operator (?) -- ie, =, >, etc -- but this is perfect, as also answered by Rodrigo Guedes above. Thank you!

Comment: @GeneBarrett No problem, happy it helped! You're definitely right about having to use the operator in quotes at certain points (such as `COUNTIF(A:A, "<>" & B1)`, but in that case you just drop the operator in the quotes and concatenate with a reference. Good luck with everything!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
=COUNTIF(C16:BT16;BU18)
```

Please note that you may need to use ";" instead of "," depending on your region.

Comment: Note that the semicolon is actually a regional thing - for instance it won't work on my (U.S.-based) system.

Comment: @RocketDonkey Good to know that. On my (Br-based) system it should be a semicolon. I though it was a general rule.

Comment: Ha, well the only reason I know is from here actually - I would paste in sample code from other people and be baffled at how it worked with semicolons :)

Comment: That did it! Brilliant -- thanks very much. Odd, though, that nothing in the Excel documentation says so -- and I had also tried =countif(c16:bt16;=bu18) and that did NOT work -- didn't think to try it w/o the = sign. Again, outstanding, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- If you are using Excel 2010, you are even luckier with [`COUNTIFS`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-sg/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx)
- By all means you may use the search range and matching range within [`countif`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countif.php)

  e.g. `=COUNTIF(SEARCH RANGE, CRITERIA RANGE)`